# How to filter union of object type by property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux, filter, union-types

Imagine the following simplified setup:

```js
import { Action, AnyAction } from 'redux'; // interface Action<Type> { type: Type } and type AnyAction = Action<any>

export type FilterActionByType<
  A extends AnyAction,
  ActionType extends string
> = A['type'] extends ActionType ? A : never;

type ActionUnion = Action<'count/get'> | Action<'count/set'>;

type CountGetAction = FilterActionByType<ActionUnion, 'count/get'>;
// expected: Action<'count/get'>
// received: never
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? (typescript 3.7 is an option)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `FilterActionByType<A, T>` to take  a union type `A` and act on each member separately, and then take all the results and unite them in a new union... that means you want `FilterActionByType<A, T>` to *distribute over unions* (at least in `A`).   You can use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to do this, by making sure that your conditional type is of the form `type FilterActionByType<A, T> = A extends ...`.  Having the bare `A` as the checked type triggers the distribution you want.

But: your conditional type is of the form `type FilterActionByType<A, T> = A["type"] extends ...`, in which `A` is "clothed" by the property lookup, and so is not distributive.  That means the `A["type"] extends ActionType` takes the whole union value for `A`, namely (in your case) `ActionUnion`.  And `ActionUnion["type"] extends "count/get"` becomes `("count/get" | "count/set") extends "count/get"`, which is false.  (`X extends (X | Y)` is always true, but `(X | Y) extends X` is not true in general.)  So you get `never`.

---

The simplest way to change what you have into a distributive conditional type is just to wrap your definition in `A extends any ? ... : never`:

```
export type FilterActionByType<
  A extends AnyAction,
  ActionType extends string
> = A extends any ? A['type'] extends ActionType ? A : never : never;

type ActionUnion = Action<'count/get'> | Action<'count/set'>;

type CountGetAction = FilterActionByType<ActionUnion, 'count/get'>;
// type CountGetAction = Action<"count/get">
```

Or you could refactor your original conditional type to be distributive without wrapping it:

```
export type FilterActionByType<
  A extends AnyAction,
  ActionType extends string
> = A extends { type: ActionType } ? A : never;

type CountGetAction = FilterActionByType<ActionUnion, 'count/get'>;
// type CountGetAction = Action<"count/get">
```

The check `A extends {type: ActionType}` is the distributive version of `A["type"] extends ActionType`.

Either way should work for you, but the latter is probably cleaner.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=1&ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#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)

Comment: Thanks, I originally discarded this because I thought that it wouldn't work with actions which have a payload, however it is perfectly fine since `{ type: string, payload: any }` still extends `{ type: string }`

Answer (score 5):

`Extract<T, U>` can be very useful for this and can be a lot simpler than a conditional type. You can think of it as 'Filter' for the following example:

```
// cat meows but doesn't bark
type Cat = { meow: true, bark: false };

// dog and coyote bark
type Coyote = { bark: true };
type Dog = { bark: true };

// all the animals
type Animal = Cat | Dog | Coyote;

// Filter / Extract Animal types that are assignable to { bark: true }
type Barkers = Extract<Animal, { bark: true }>;


// Result: 
// type Barkers == Dog | Coyote
```

Probably less likely to be useful for OP question, but there's some cool functionality for [filtering in mapped types too](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) (from TS 4.1).

Answer (score 4):

The best solution from [Piotr Lewandowski](https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c) :

```
type FilterFlags<Base, Condition> = {
    [Key in keyof Base]: 
        Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
};
type AllowedNames<Base, Condition> = 
        FilterFlags<Base, Condition>[keyof Base];
type SubType<Base, Condition> = 
        Pick<Base, AllowedNames<Base, Condition>>;
```