# Typescript generic array.find() method that extracts result type from the input tuple

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a widget hierarchy like this:

```
interface IBaseWidget {
  type: string;
}

interface IButton extends IBaseWidget {
  type: 'button';
  title: string;
}

interface ICheckbox extends IBaseWidget {
  type: 'checkbox';
  checked: boolean;
}

type IWidget = IButton | ICheckbox;
type IWidgetType = IWidget['type'];
```

I want to write a method to find all widgets of a given type.

How do I type this function so that it can "extract" the correct member types from the input array?

Basically:

```
function findByType(widgets: IWidget[], type: IWidgetType) {
  return widgets.filter(x => x.type === type);
}

// How to make this IButton[] ?
const buttons = findByType([], 'button');
```

Bonus points if this can be absolutely generic, in that I don't even need to know about `IWidget`, but the tuple variants are extracted straight from the input array type.

Eg. I can do something like:

```
const input: ({type: 'A'} | {type: 'B'} | {type: 'C'})[] = [];
const result = findByType(input, 'B'); // result: {type: 'B'}[]
```

Sandbox: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcIHVgAmA5hGMgN4BQyyYAngA4QBcyWYUoRA3JQL6VKoSLEQoMAVzBgA9iGQQAHpBAEsaTDnzFSFarUYtkAcgBGU2SGO8aYYGAA2R9pxA9+g4dHhI0AYQALCAQAa1MZRQVlCFV1DGw8QhIyKltDVmMEINDwxWt9LOCQiAJWcJknOBBeAUp6JjRtZOQAXg0LOWQAH39ssIjeevEm0gAVQ1bGpNIAbWMh4wBdXkoYCRAEO06YUAJ0OnGmAAoAd2mwLFZUEbAZxYAaAyYrm8OIAEo9GihSCSh5M46C4AOh2DhER0iLQAfMhFMChq0Wm0hu8aoIAPQY5AACRkJ1oMmQAFs4MVaAFgHF0B0QHdkAB+SgIOTsZDmaSsyY7VT7N5HO6PMy04xooA

Comment: Initial attempt but a bit clunky: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcIHVgAmA5hGMgN4BQyyYAngA4QBcyWYUoRA3JQL6VKoSLEQoMAVzBgA9iGQQAHpBAEsaTDnzFSFarUYtkAcgBGU2SGO8aYYGAA2R9pxA9+g4dHhI0AYQALCAQAa1MZRQVlCFV1DGw8QhIyKltDVmMEINDwxWt9LOCQiAJWcJknOBBeAUp6JjRtZOQAXg0LOWQAH39ssIjeevEm0gAVQ1bGpNIAbWMh4wBdXi9RX3GmAFk4BiiVNWQAJWCZKAIAHlQRsA2IABopnTAAPj0aGgAic2k5D9ZJH7VfSfQo5CJ-XpFXI1QQwCQgBB2TowUAEdB0W7nUZ7GIHK7TG6GZ4ACgA7gSsP9rjNFg8hqxRgBKVLIKCkCRQeTkp5YAB0KIcIjJBNar25yV5Q1aLTaQ0ZyGwyFu2wYM1GixpMMoAHptcgABIyUm0GTIAC2cGKtACwDi6A6IBpyAA-JQEHJ2MhvpZ1G0Uap0bdiTSHmYHcZGdwgA

Comment: Is it possible to be variant 2? Eg. that I don't need to generate a type-map ahead of time?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to get something like that working, I understand that's limiting and makes it hard to be generic. I didn't post that attempt as an answer because I'm sure there's a better way. I'll let you know if I figure it out!

Comment: I'm trying too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this [excellent previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584071/how-to-filter-union-of-object-type-by-property-in-typescript) as inspiration for an adapted version that should work well for your use case:

```
interface IBaseWidget {
  type: string;
}

interface IButton extends IBaseWidget {
  type: "button";
  title: string;
}

interface ICheckbox extends IBaseWidget {
  type: "checkbox";
  checked: boolean;
}

type IWidget = IButton | ICheckbox;

type FilterWidgetByType<
  W extends IWidget,
  Type extends string
> = W extends any ? (W["type"] extends Type ? W : never) : never;

function findByType<T extends IWidget["type"]>(widgets: IWidget[], type: T) {
  return widgets.filter(
    (widget): widget is FilterWidgetByType<IWidget, T> => widget.type === type
  );
}

// How to make this IButton[] ?
const buttons = findByType([], "button");
const checkboxes = findByType([], "checkbox");
```

Here is the [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcIHVgAmA5hGMgN4BQyyYAngA4QBcyWYUoRA3JQL6VKoSLEQoMAVzBgA9iGQQAHpBAEsaTDnzFSFarUYtkAcgBGU2SGO8aYYGAA2R9pxA9+g4dHhI0AYQALCAQAa1MZRQVlCFV1DGw8QhIyKltDVmMEINDwxWt9LOCQiAJWcJknOBBeAUp6JjRtZOQAXg0LOWQAH39ssIjeevEm0gAVQ1bGpNIAbWMh4wBdXkolBhkoMiHkADFgBxERsHQ6caYAHn1cKJU1KZ0wABp9M5QlW-UXLkoAPknr94xO5VOjIAD8yFwcwWixuQPUr3BkOQrBAEAAbtAUcg0ZioCsYBIQAg7J0YKACCdXudRnDYvdkq8fgAKADu0zAWFYqCOM0WjwMTFYowAlHoaFBSBIoPJ2Q8sAA6ckHaDMtkckWsOXNYDqPYqqBHKmGc48jkC0Z-Fp-bWkBXbFqOwUQEU1QQAendyAAEjJWbQZMgALZwYq0AK69rSOR88GUBBydjIczRkDqNrk1TGpjMvkCswdKyu+OJsiFHIRCDp5CZymnQy5-kmcv9PKuoA).

Comment: Fantastic! Didn't think it would be so simple.

Comment: I don't fully understand the `FilterWidgetByType` type, but it certainly seems to work. I'm going to spend some time trying to understand it.